Using different databases for each client using my webapp? looking for suggestions on how to scale
We are a team of 3, 1 frontend dev, 1 backend dev and data analyst. We made a webapp that is mostly built on SAP technology(SAP UI5, SAP hana..). Our app takes raw data from client's servers, analyzes it in backend and displays it on the webapp. Right now, we only have 2 clients, the frontend is hosted on Cloud Foundry for each client separately and the backend is running on the client's on premises servers. since we only have 2 clients, we made a different client folder for each one included in the assets of their separate hosted frontends (containing stuff like images and the different routes to access the data from the respective backend).
Right now we are thinking about scalability, changing the frontend or the backend means going through and changing each 1 separately for the clients. also getting new clients will be probably the end of us.
We are considering making it all work in the cloud so it is easier to maintain and scale but since we are inexperienced we don't know how that would look like. Do we host 1 instance of the frontend and make user accounts which each save access data to the users' respective database where we get the raw data and have the backend on the cloud too? is that even possible to connect to different databases in different sessions? are we missing an easier solution ? any general suggestions would be truly appreciated.
Painful updating process and inability to take new clients.
